# Add a static option to a HTML Select along with dynamic options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some JQuery that gets a JSON array and populates a HTML Select dropdown menu, and it works fine:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: urlLink,
        success: function(data) {
            var sel = $('#siteChangeSelect');
            sel.empty();

            var SiteList = (data.sites);

            $('#chSBtn').show();

            $.each(SiteList, function(i, item){
                sel.append('<option value ="' + SiteList[i].customerReference + '">' + SiteList[i].customerSite + '</option>');

            });

        }
    });
```

However, what I want to do is to add an option to the list that the user can select a default option such as "Use All Available". How can I add this option to the bottom of the dynamically generated list?

Comment: `append` one more `option` after the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you would dynamically:

```
$.each(SiteList, function(i, item){
  sel.append('<option value ="' + SiteList[i].customerReference + '">' + SiteList[i].customerSite + '</option>');
});
sel.append('<option value ="all" selected>Use All Available</option>');
```

However I'd append it to the top, not to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've added it but every time the list is generated the "Use All" option is removed and never replaced?

Comment: Did you append it after `sel.empty();`?

Comment: I copied your answer and put it outside the `$.each` loop. This is all placed after `sel.empty();`

Comment: I don't know what's happened but it's just started working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Created a simple [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/joseftw/8XK7C/) for you with the following code:

```
var sel = $('#siteChangeSelect');
var siteList = [];
siteList.push({ customerReference : "Test1", customerSite : "Test1"});
siteList.push({ customerReference : "Test2", customerSite : "Test2"});
siteList.push({ customerReference : "Test3", customerSite : "Test3"});
siteList.push({ customerReference : "Test4", customerSite : "Test4"});
siteList.push({ customerReference : "Test5", customerSite : "Test5"});
siteList.push({ customerReference : "Test6", customerSite : "Test6"});

$.each(siteList, function(i, item){
    sel.append('<option value ="' + siteList[i].customerReference + '">' +             siteList[i].customerSite + '</option>');

});

//Adds to the bottom
$(sel).append('<option value="newValueBottom">New Value Bottom</option>');
//Adds to the top
$(sel).prepend('<option value="newValueTop">New Value Top</option>');
```